# Can you store state in a custom UICollectionViewCell? Or can the state get erased (like when the cell scrolls off the screen)?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

If I create a UICollectionViewCell subclass like:

```
class StudentCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var student: Student?
}
```

And in my controller I implement UICollectionView's didSelectItemAtIndexPath and set the variable:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let studentCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? StudentCell {
        studentCell.student = self.someStudent
    }
}
```

When I click on the cell it should set student, but if the cell is scrolled off screen it seems like the whole cell might get wiped and when it comes back on screen it would need to rebuild itself in **cellForItemAtIndexPath**.

The problem I have is that I have a **UICollectionView** with cells that do not scroll off the screen that I'm storing data in.  Because they don't leave the screen I assume they should not get wiped, but one of the cells does not seem to keep it's variable, which makes me think maybe it's getting wiped and I may need to move the state outside of the cells to a dictionary or something and in **didSelectItemAtIndexPath** instead of setting the variable in the cell I'd set the dictionary.  Whenever I need to access the data instead of asking the cell for it I'd look it up in the dictionary.

But either way, I was wondering if it's possible (or a bad idea) to set it in the cell or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, cells in both `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` can (will) be reused at the systems discretion and should not be used to store state information, only display information.  Specifically, both views will reuse cells when they are scrolled off-screen, but there's no guarantee this is the only time they'll be reused.  The usual way to handle this is to define some kind of cell data object which stores the data for each cell (visible and not) and refresh the cell view from that as needed/requested.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was the way to do it but was trying to see if I could shortcut things.  I now store the state outside of the cells. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tables display their data in cells. A cell is related to a row but it’s not exactly the same. A cell is a view that shows a row of data that happens to be visible at that moment. If your table can show 10 rows at a time on the screen, then it only has10 cells, even though there may be hundreds of rows with actual data. Whenever a row scrolls off the screen and becomes invisible, its cell will be re-used for a new row that scrolls into the screen.

[image: Cell/Row example]